# python, import csv file, read columns and rows, remove blank spaces, convert strings to real numbers

Tags: whitespace, typeconverter

I'm having trouble with importing a csv file into python and having it separate the information. I want to also remove all the blank spaces and convert the numbers (which are strings right now) into integers.  Here is what I have so far. These lines work but do not accomplish the task of removing the blank spaces and converting the strings to integers.

```
filename = 'myfile.csv'
f = open(filename, 'r')
read = f.readlines()

print(read)

for i in range(len(read)):
    read[i] = read[i].split(',')
print(read)
header = read[0]
print(header)

info = {}
cntr = 0
for name in header:
    info[name] = [line[cntr] for line in read]
    cntr += 1
print(info)
```

I searched through past examples on this forum and this is what I tried to do to have the blank spaces removed but now I'm lost:

```
import csv
aList = []
with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace = True, delimiter = ',', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        aList.append(row)
    print(aList) 

info = {}
cntr = 0
for i in aList:
    info[aList] = [line[cntr] for line in reader]
    cntr += 1
```

print(info)

Comment: for blank space removal, you can use str.replace(" ","") Example, str="Hello hi";str.replace(" ","");print str which will give 'Hellohi'.

Comment: Can you give a sample of input and output that you expect!

Answer (score 0):

```
#sample input
#1 23,456,789
#11 2,11 3,114


import csv
aList = []
with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace = True, delimiter = ',', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        aList.append(row)
    print(aList)

info = {}
cntr = 0
print [map(int,[j.replace(" ","") for j in i]) for i in aList]
#[[123,456,789][112,113,114]]
```

Explanation - making the last line simple, and breaking into parts,

```
#[i for i in aList] gives [["1 23","456","789"]["11 2","11 3","114"]]
#[j.replace(" ","") for j in i] gives [["123","456","789"]["112","113","114"]]

#[map(int,[j.replace(" ","") for j in i]) for i in aList] 
#maps all string in list to int and gives [[123,456,789][112,113,114]]
```